# Using R Markdown chunks in R Sweave(Knitr)

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, sweave

I have a R Markdown file that has my notes and chunks of code. I now want to write a R Sweave(Knitr) document to publish a paper using those chunks. I do not want to cut and paste the chunks, I rather call them directly. That way if I update the chunks, I don't have to do it in two places. It seems like it would be simple enough, but I can not figure it out. My code is as follows, `test.rmd` is my mark down document, foo is the chunk in the `rmd` file.

Test.rnw

```
 <<Setup>>===
 read_chunk('test.rmd') 
 @
 <<foo>>==
 @
```

Test.rmd

````
```{r foo, echo=TRUE}
   print(summary(cars))
```
````

I would expect a summary of cars to be displayed in the output of the compilation of `test.rnw` into a PDF. But I don't. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the help page? "Note

This function can only be used in a chunk which is not cached (chunk option cache = FALSE), and the code is read and stored in the current session without being executed (to actually run the code, you have to use a chunk with a corresponding label)."

Comment: I thought that is what I was doing.  By default, cache=FALSE and I used a chunk with a corresponding label. My chuck code is called foo, and I am calling it using <<foo>>==. That is, unless I completely missed the boat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read_chunk` reads chunks from r script so call `purl` before `read_chunk`:

```
<<Setup>>=
knit_patterns$set(all_patterns[["md"]])
purl("test.Rmd")
knit_patterns$set(all_patterns[["rnw"]])
read_chunk("test.R")
@

<<foo>>=
@
```

Comment: When I run purl and read_chunk from the console, I get a R file with my chunks. I then copied and pasted in your example into my rnw file. When the rnw file is compiled into a PDF, the R file is generated, but is empty. I made sure that my dir are set correctly and that the file is being read in by purl. So, I am a loss of why I am getting an empty R file.

Comment: you may need to set patterns explicitly. See updated.

Comment: Thank you so very much! It does exactly what I needed. This will make my studies and research so much easier. Again, thank you so very much.